# Sensing plugged in 3.5mm jack with the TRRS contacts

Tags: circuit-design, audio, plug, trrs

I am using the pictured TRRS connector and want to detect whether a plug is plugged in via the builtin switches (pins 2/3/4). However, the switches seem to be connected to the audio lines as well. Surely connecting a resistor divider/voltages/other sensing would affect the audio signal?

Preferably I don't want to use "overkill" ICs - I don't need any more amplification. I've seen the TI TPA6166A2 mentioned that can do this, but it only seems to be available in BGA (and is far more complex than I think I need). (However, I am willing to find a hand-solderable IC if it is the only way.)

Other answers have mentioned the switches but not specifically how to use them to detect a plug without affecting the audio signal. What sort of circuit would let me detect these switches opening in this way?

[image: Schematic diagram of connector]

(I have bridged together Left and Right channels because my audio source is Mono. I have designed this for "Apple"/AHJ pinout jacks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thin rectangle between pins 4 and 6 is probably an insulator that provides a mechanical push to open pins 3 and 4.

When the plug is inserted, pins 3 and 4 open.

Connect one end of a resistor to pin 4 and the other end to 5V. Connect pin 3 to ground. When the plug is inserted the voltage on pin 4 will switch from 0V to 5V.

This will not affect the audio signal.

There are many other ways to use this switch.

Comment: Out of interest, what would I have to do if there wasn't that separate isolated pair of contacts?

Comment: You would have tomonitor the audioncurrents or the circuit impedance.